# Android-unable to post picture to wall using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problem to picture to wall using facebook sdk. Below is my code.

Facebook permission dialog on start of activity:

```
fb = new Facebook(fb_id);

fb.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream",
                "read_stream", "offline_access","read_friendlists"}, new DialogListener(){

public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
    Log.e("oncomplete","value");
    if (values.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("oncomplete","value is empty");
        return;
    }
    if (!values.containsKey("POST")) {
        token = fb.getAccessToken();
    }
}
public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {}
public void onError(DialogError e){}    
public void onCancel() {}
});
```

On click of button send feed to wall

```
public void onClick(View v){
if(v==post_to_wall){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fb token " + token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message what){
            finish();
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            publishToFriendsWall(friends_id);   
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
    thread.start();             
    }
}
```

publish to friends wall method

```
public void publishToFriendsWall(String friends_id){
        if(fb.isSessionValid()){
        try{                                
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, token);
                params.putString("message", edittext.getText().toString());
                params.putString("link", "http://www.mysite.com");
            params.putString("caption", "my caption");
            params.putString("description", "description of my link.  Click the link to find out more.");
            params.putString("name", "my name");
            //params.putString("picture", "mypic url");

           fb.request(((friends_id == null) ? "me" : friends_id) + "/feed", params, "POST");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d(null, "Fb post to wall error occured " + e.getClass().getName());
        }               
    }
    }
```

the problem is when i put the following code

```
params.putString("picture", "mypic url");
```

there nothing were post to the wall and if i comment the above code it's working fine, I read through the facebook graph api documentation to post a picture it is required access token and valid url for the picture. I've done all that by get access token and the url is valid. what is wrong with my code? There also no error was caught. The only thing i get in logcat is warning like

```
Key picture expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String. the default value <null> was return
Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
    at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
    at com.facebook.android.Util.encodePostBody(Util.java:63)
    at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:182)
    at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:563)
```

Comment: actually picture should be of type byte, but y r u trying to use a String there?

Comment: yeah a string but in type of url, because most of the example on web they put url for the picture. the graph path api documentation from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ also state it required the valid string url.

Answer (score 0):

```
mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
    boolean validity=mFacebook.isSessionValid();

    try
    {
    byte[] data = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

     opts.inSampleSize=4;           
     Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(st_imagepath,opts);
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     data = baos.toByteArray();


      Bundle params = new Bundle();
      params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, mFacebook.getAccessToken());
      params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
      params.putString("caption", caption);



      params.putByteArray("picture", data);

      AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

      mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

use this working code. Ur problem will be solved